# How to hide toolbar contributions from third party plugins based on perspective

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have used a third-party plug-in to my rcp application that adds some  UI contribution to my application. basically it provides me a UI editing functionality like graphity that we are showing in a separate perspective. it also add some toolbar and menu-bar contributions.

my question is can we hide the toolbar contribution from a third party plug-ins depending on active perspective? that's mean let's say i  have two perspective and i want only one perspective will show the toolbar contribution from this third party plugns but not the other one.

thank you advance for you help.

Comment: Have you tried [Activities](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/)?

Comment: yes, i have tried but did not work.

Comment: Try to remove unnecessary elements programmatically. There are number of topics on SO about how to do so.

Comment: i do not want to remove unnecessary elements. i need to hide it based on active perspective